# How do I whitelist Facebook crawler in a PHP project?

Tags: php, html, facebook, user-agent, whitelist

I need to implement Facebook social plugins in my site mostly  based on html and php. I have a login system so in order to do this I have to whitelist the Facebook Crawler so it can scrape my site. On the documentation it is stated that I need to whitelist either the following user agent strings:

```
facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)
facebookexternalhit/1.1
```

Or the ip addresses that result from running the following command which are the ones that the crawler uses:

```
whois -h whois.radb.net -- '-i origin AS32934' | grep ^route
```

I am clueless on how to whitelist something, does it has to be done on my .htaccess document? Or does it has to be done on my php script? Or my server system?
Also, where do I run the command above to get the ip addresses?

I thank you in advance.

Comment: It has to be done in the code that doesn't let Facebook in